# BigDecimal output does not contain precise decimal values?

Tags: java, double, precision, bigdecimal, autoboxing

Practice problem using BigDecimal for the first time.
My main method output should be:

> Area of circle with radius 8.5949958is:
>   232.081671383290563028029402608911005665488497019210725540793500930304148269265220664195247142820189371870652494944664567810832522809505462646484375
>
> Area of circle with radius 3.440393959403938E7is:
>   3718483500498323.66662697460176592346057689232315135847190735857072463126614392248114882022491656243801116943359375

however, that's not what is printed. I get a value of

```
232.081671383290555535978683110442943871021270751953125
```

for circle one, and a value of `3718483500498323.563695` for circle two. 
A colleague informed me that I need to use BigDecimals for every value in order to for the output to be precise, but I'm under the impression that I'm already doing this.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class Circle
{
private BigDecimal radius = new BigDecimal("0.0");

public Circle()
{
   setRadius(0.0);
} 
public void setRadius(double r)
{
   this.radius = new BigDecimal(r);
}
public BigDecimal findCircleArea(double radius)
{
  this.setRadius(radius);
  BigDecimal Pi = new BigDecimal("3.14159");
  BigDecimal rad = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(radius, 2.0));
  BigDecimal a = Pi.multiply(rad);

  return a;
}

}
```

Merge if you need to, but I've looked around and haven't been able to find an answer, it's really frustrating me.

Comment: That's a nice riddle. I personally have no idea how to receive these numbers, if it is not misunderstanding of the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have misunderstood your task or you missed something in the input data. I can prove it easily on a mathematical basis.

Consider your first example: on the input you have a value equal to `8.5949958`. Even without doing multiplication of this number on itself (square) we can estimate a maximum number of digits in its fractional part: it can not be more than `14` digits, because `10^-7 * 10^-7 = 10^-14`.
If we will take it as a `BigDecimal` value and square it, we receive:

```
BigDecimal rad = BigDecimal.valueOf(radius).pow(2);
```

`=73.87395280201764` which is the exact value of square of the given input. I.e. there is no lose of precision here.

Going to the next step. Next, you multiply this number on `3.14159`. Again, using the same approach we can estimate the maximum number of digits in the meaningful fractional part: it can not be more than `19` digits, because `10^-5 * 10^-14 = 10^-19`. Let's do this multiplication:

`BigDecimal a = Pi.multiply(rad);`

`=232.0816713832905976476` - 19 digits. So we didn't lose any precision here.

From what follows that this long numbers, which you expect as an output, simply can not be received for the given input. Or you are missing something in the input, or this is a mistake in the task.

Comment: It's a possibility that the main main (written by my professor) is incorrect.          Circle c = new Circle();
      double r1 = 8.5949958;
      System.out.println("Area of circle with radius " + r1 + " is: ");
      System.out.println(c.findCircleArea(r1));
      System.out.println();
      
      double r2 = 34403939.594039382;
      System.out.println("Area of circle with radius " + r2 + " is: ");
      System.out.println(c.findCircleArea(r2));

Answer (score 0):

To get all those digits of precision, you need to transform `double` values to BigDecimals as soon as possible, since `double` values, being inexact, contain “hidden” extra digits that will contribute to the scale of the result.  Avoid the use of Strings and do not do any `double` math.

Essentially, change this:

```
BigDecimal Pi = new BigDecimal("3.14159");
BigDecimal rad = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(radius, 2.0));
```

to this:

```
BigDecimal Pi = new BigDecimal(3.14159);
BigDecimal rad = new BigDecimal(radius).pow(2);
```

Comment: He should not change the initialization of `Pi` from `String` to `double`, and he should specify a lot more digits.

Comment: @EJP Ideally, yes, but he left this comment on a now-deleted answer:  “The professor that assigned this to me had instructed to use only 3.14159 for this problem; I've tried it with Math.PI and I got an even more inaccurate answer. He noted that I'll only find the correct answer using 3.14159.”